# Setting python variable from array dict value?

Tags: python, json

Learning python for the first time and it's I'm reading the JSON and decoding it correctly. I can loop through the names with the first for loop so I figured I was getting the value of names correctly. When I try to set that value to a variable I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./logger.py", line 70, in <module>
    winnerName = jsonData['players'][winner].get('name')
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode
```

Python code:

```
jsonData = json.load(open('file.json'))

## Functions correctly and prints each name out.
for i in range(0,7):
  print jsonData['players'][i].get('name')

gameMatches = jsonData['games'][game]['matches']
for match in gameMatches:
  winnerBool = 1
  winner = -1
  loser = -1
  winnerName = ""
  loserName = ""
  matchCounter = 1

  ## Set the winner first then check to see who lost
  for key, value in sorted(match.iteritems(), reverse=True):
    if winnerBool:
      winner = value
  ## This is where the error keeps pointing
      winnerName = jsonData['players'][winner].get('name')
      winnerBool = 0
    elif winner != value:
      loserName = jsonData['players'][loser].get('name')
      loser = value

  print winnerName
  print loserName
```

JSON file:

```
{
   "players":[
      {"name":"Donatello","img":"\/img\/players\/1.jpg","rol":"\/img\/players\/r1.jpg"},
      {"name":"Leonardo","img":"\/img\/players\/2.jpg","rol":"\/img\/players\/r2.jpg"},
      {"name":"Michelangelo","img":"\/img\/players\/3.jpg","rol":"\/img\/players\/r3.jpg"},
      {"name":"Raphael","img":"img\/players\/4.jpg","rol":"img\/players\/r4.jpg"},
      {"name":"Shredder","img":"\/img\/players\/5.jpg","rol":"\/img\/players\/r5.jpg"},
      {"name":"Rocksteady","img":"\/img\/players\/6.jpg","rol":"\/img\/players\/r6.jpg"},
      {"name":"Bebop","img":"\/img\/players\/7.jpg","rol":"\/img\/players\/r7.jpg"},
      {"name":"Foot Soldier","img":"\/img\/players\/8.jpg","rol":"\/img\/players\/r8.jpg"}
      ],
   "games":[
      {"matches":[
         {"player1":"0","player2":"2","winner":"0"},
         {"player1":"1","player2":"3","winner":"3"},
         {"player1":"4","player2":"5","winner":"4"},
         {"player1":"6","player2":"7","winner":"6"},
         {"player1":"0","player2":"3","winner":"0"},
         {"player1":"4","player2":"6","winner":"4"},
         {"player1":"0","player2":"4","winner":"0"}
         ]
      },
      {"matches":[
         {"player1":"0","player2":"2","winner":"2"},
         {"player1":"1","player2":"3","winner":"3"},
         {"player1":"4","player2":"5","winner":"4"},
         {"player1":"6","player2":"7","winner":"7"},
         {"player1":"2","player2":"3","winner":"2"},
         {"player1":"4","player2":"7","winner":"4"},
         {"player1":"2","player2":"4","winner":"4"}
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Could you post the full traceback? And the full `JSON` file? Because what you posted has no `'games'` section, but your code refers to `jsonData['games']`.

Comment: Without checking whether you actually access the correct data, your JSON does not contain any numbers, only strings. So `winner` contains a string. You have to convert it to a number first.

Comment: "Foot Clan"? Don't you mean "Foot Soldier"?

Comment: Sorry about cropping it, didn't know how much to include. I've added the fulltraceback and JSON.

Thanks Ignacio lol didn't notice I typed that instead of singular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
winner = int(value)
```

To convert from `"1"` (string) to `1` (integer)

**EDITED** to clarify:

when you do this....

```
for key, value in sorted(match.iteritems(), reverse=True):
    #...
```

...your key and value variables will be strings. I am assuming you are iterating over this part of your JSON:

```
{"matches":[
     {"player1":"0","player2":"2","winner":"0"},
     {"player1":"1","player2":"3","winner":"3"},
```

Therefore, when you assign...

```
winner = value
```

...and try to look up...

```
winnerName = jsonData['players'][winner].get('name')
```

...you get a...

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode
```

...because you are saying:

```
x = list["4"]
```

where it should say:

```
x = list[4]
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't give enough information about the problem the question has been edited to clarify what is the issue. I'm trying to get the name value in the players array and set it to a variable.

Comment: Oh wow yeah that makes sense now. You did answer it but I was thinking the issue was with storing the name not the winner/loser "int" being a string. Thank you.